# coloring cells of excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, colors, cells

I want to color some particular cells of excel sheet in c#. but I am not getting it..
I am using the code as:

```
  dsNew.Tables[0].Columns[j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DeepPink);
```

but this is not wrking..
how this can be done..
please do something..
it is giving an error "cannot resolve symbol'interior'"

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Range.Interior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.interior.aspx) property:

```
Range data_cell = work_sheet.Cells[row, column];
data_cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DeepPink);
```

where `work_sheet` is the Excel.Worksheet you wish to change the cells of.  `row` and `column` or the indices of the cells to change.

Your example may be returning an object for the column indexer.  Try this:

```
((Range)dsNew.Tables[0].Columns[j]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DeepPink);
```