# Why can't change the fill color of a cell using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

Based on :

[coloring cells of excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859857/coloring-cells-of-excel-sheet)

I put this line of code

```
Range data_cell = work_sheet.Cells[row, column];
data_cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DeepPink);
```

I added the System.Drawing dll file + added the import line in my file

```
using System.Drawing;
```

but I still receive this message:

```
cannot resolve symbol "ColorTranslator"
```

Any suggestions to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background color of a cell,

```
                Range myRange = work_sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
                myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6;
```

This will paint the A1 cell

EDIT: Couldn't find a good reference for `ColorIndex`, but [here's](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/Ee692862.colorindex%28en-us,TechNet.10%29.jpg) an image of all of the colors
6, in our example, is Yellow.

Comment: It should not be necessary to call `Select()` before setting the color.